# Shadow inside UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I am working on iPhone application development and have come across shadows of UIView.

I know how to show shadows to a UIView but what I am actually interested in is to drop shadow inside the UIView.

Like when I set shadow properties of a UIView the shadow is dropped behind the view. I want it to come over the view so that the view looks as if it is pressed inside.

Example of such view is UITextField with roundedRect styling.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on the final effect you want to achieve.

The easies way would be a custom image with a prebacked shadow as background. This will give the illusion of a recession in the surface of the view. You can then add subviews to it as usual.

Alternatively, you can override the *drawRect:* method and draw the view as you like there, "inverted drop shadow" included.